# Java annotation to execute some code before and after method

Tags: java, swing, annotations, mouse-cursor

I'm writing an swing app and i'd like to have 'wait' cursor when some methods are executed. We can do it this way:

```
public void someMethod() {
    MainUI.getInstance().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
    //method code
    MainUI.getInstance().setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
}
```

What I'd like to achieve is a java annotation, that would set wait cursor before method execution and set it back to normal after execution. So previous example would look something like this

```
@WaitCursor    
public void someMethod() {
    //method code
}
```

How can i achieve this? Suggestions about other variants of solving this problem are also welcome. 
Thanks!

P.S. - We use Google Guice in our project, but i don't get how to solve the problem using it. If someone would provide me with simple example of similar problem, that would be very helpful

Comment: AOP? http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/aspect-oriented-programming-spring-aop.html?

Comment: You could also use AOP that comes with Google Guice since you already have it on your project.

Comment: @StanislavL I guess you mean [Aspect Oriented Programming with Spring AOP](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/aspect-oriented-programming-spring-aop.html).  That was the top hit I got extracting the words from the page of the URL and searching the site.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You may use AspectJ, or use Google Guice which bring its own AOP.

The object having the method annotated with your `WaitCursor` annotation must be injected with Guice.

You define your annotation

```
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(ElementType.METHOD)
@interface WaitCursor {}
```

You add a MethodInterceptor :

```
public class WaitCursorInterceptor implements MethodInterceptor {
    public Object invoke(MethodInvocation invocation) throws Throwable {
        // show the cursor
        MainUI.getInstance().setCursor(Cursor.getPredefinedCursor(Cursor.WAIT_CURSOR));
        // execute the method annotated with `@WaitCursor`
        Object result = invocation.proceed();
        // hide the waiting cursor
        MainUI.getInstance().setCursor(Cursor.getDefaultCursor());
        return result;
    }
}
```

And define a module where you bind the interceptor on any method having your annotation.

```
public class WaitCursorModule extends AbstractModule {
    protected void configure() {
        bindInterceptor(Matchers.any(), Matchers.annotatedWith(WaitCursor.class), new WaitCursorInterceptor());
    }
}
```

You can see more advanced uses on [this page](http://code.google.com/p/google-guice/wiki/AOP)

Comment: Not sure how do I inject the object that holds the method with the annotations, an example will be appreciated.

Comment: I am using this solution with Quarkus, but I am not able to build the app. I keep getting this error:

`[ERROR] WaitCursorModule.java:[25,9] cannot find symbol
  symbol:   method bindInterceptor(com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher<java.lang.Object>,com.google.inject.matcher.Matcher<java.lang.reflect.AnnotatedElement>, WaitCursorModule)`

Any advice will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to look at using [around() advice in AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/semantics-advice.html) in conjunction with your annotation to associate the around() advice with all methods that are qualified with your annotation.