# Can I make code run before the constructor using annotations

Tags: java, annotations, guice

I am using Guice to create and inject instances in my application.

For **testing** purposes I created a class that is responsible for creating all the **static** instances needed for a specific test class and inject them. Let's call this class GuiceGraphBuilder.

I want to create and initiate the GuiceGraphBuilder before my mock / test class constructor is called, as some of my mock classes requires the injection to happen on construction time.

Currently I am using a static constructor that initiate GuiceGraphBuilder and populate bunch of static fields.

Is there a way to use some kind of annotation to make a code run before the constructor does?
I have seen an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195015/java-annotation-to-execute-some-code-before-and-after-method) that uses Guice, but this of course is not good in my case, since I want to create the Guice injector in the generated code.

Comment: Couldn't our test code create `GuiceGraphBuilder` before creating your fakes? Could you provide a bit of code?

Comment: I can, but I want to use an annotation instead to make the code cleaner.

Comment: I personally find straight-forward code test code easier to read and maintain than magic annotations

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you test using junit? Then you have the lifecycle hooks

- @BeforeClass - run once before first test (use for static setup)
- @Before - run before every test method
- @After - run after each test method
- @AfterClass - run once after all tests finished

I suppose that, arbitrary from guice, you will be able to solve your problem by matching init and clean up to the correct phase.