# Use annotion to compute elapsed time of method

Tags: java, annotations

let say that I have code below.

```
  public void someMethod(){
        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        //do something
        long durationTime = System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime;
        saveDurationTimeToLogger(durationTime);
  }
```

It works, but it is too long. So it made my mind to use annotation. It should look like this (function is same as code above).

```
 @TimeWatch
 public void someMethod(){
      //do something
 }
```

I was wondering how to do it, because I want to use it for arbitrary method in project (with many main methods), but I didn't figure out it. Do you have any idea?

Comment: You can try with spring AOP if you're using spring.

Comment: AOP is definitely the way to go, which framework to use depends on the rest of your project. Besides that you could also just use a profiler which would slow down your methods but normally gives good hints on where to look when optimizing.

Comment: Using AOP only for measuring method execution times seems like overkill. I would start by using a profiler like [VisualVM](https://visualvm.java.net/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an [Aspect Oriented Programming](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming) tool to solve this problem without writing masses of code yourself. [Spring AOP](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/aop.html) is the most popular (Here's a [good introduction and example](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/06/simple-introduction-to-aop.html)), or if you're not using Spring consider [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/next/progguide/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do something before and after some code I think you need two annotations.

You can do your own annotation like this:
[Java annotation to execute some code before and after method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195015/java-annotation-to-execute-some-code-before-and-after-method)

Comment: An Interceptor can execute code both before and after the actual method call. It just wraps the method invocation, performs the checks it wants (has annotation X? has parameter Y?), performs the logic, calls the original method, and then can performa additional logic. No need for two annotations unless the tasks before and after are not related.

Comment: In fact, the answer you link to does exactly that...

Comment: Oh jea thats right. U can do it with just one.