# Repeated code for validating request in each controller

Tags: java, spring

I have bunch of Rest controllers. for example:

```
@RequestMapping(path="/{groupId}",method=RequestMethod.PUT)
public void update(@RequestBody GroupDto groupDto, @PathVariable long groupId, Principal principal, BindingResult result) throws IOException {
    updateGroupDtoValidator.validate(groupDto, result);
    if (result.hasErrors()) {
        throw new ValidationException();
    }
    groupService.update(groupId, groupDto, principal.getName());
}
```

In each method controller I have to repeat making a call to validate and checking the result for errors. IS there any better way ? Is it possible to configure @Validated somehow to validate the input data from the client ?

**Update1** I have several validators. For example, I have `UpdateGroupDtoValidator` which validates a GroupDto object when it's passed to the `Update` Rest endpoint. I have another validator `CreateGroupDtoValidator` which validates `GroupDto` when dto is passed to the `Create` Rest endpoint.

Comment: This might be of some assistance https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12195015/java-annotation-to-execute-some-code-before-and-after-method

Though this is probably what you are looking for: [Spring MVC Interceptor](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/)

Comment: You should consider using the @Valid annotation as explained here http://www.baeldung.com/spring-mvc-custom-validator.

Comment: @Mustafa AFAIK `@Valid` validates the object according to the annotations used in the class it belongs to. I cannot do that as I validate object of one class differently based on different scenarios. Please see Update1

Comment: You are right the notation won't be sufficient for your use-case. I would try @sbjavateam's suggestion, it seems to fit the bill.

Comment: Would it help to localize validation to the service layer only (inside Update/Create, etc).  The controller could call service directly, and service validator throw ValidationException("Description of problem") if DTO is invalid.  Or does each controller method call a unique validator?

Answer (score 2):

Arian is right.But if you need to validate not for all method and controllers (you can contoler what should be validated and where) you can do it via spring aspects like this 
https://www.abtosoftware.com/blog/form-validation-using-aspect-oriented-programming-aop-in-spring-framework

Answer (score 0):

You can define a [Spring MVC Interceptor](http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring-mvc-interceptor-example/) which will as its name suggests intercepts your calls before they reach the controller, you can perform your validation at that point.

Comment: Doesn't spring interceptors intercept all calls ? And I have different endpoints and they use different dto's and each one uses different validators for different scenarios. I don't think using interceptors is a good idea.

Comment: Yes it does that and based on the update it wont resolve your problem, not in a healthy way at least, sbjavateam solution is what you need.